# From Latex to Maple

Tags: conversion

I was wondering if there is a software or a package for Maple 18 that could allow the conversion from a Latex equation to a Maple-style equation. I searched online but I could only find the "opposite" (from Maple to Latex). Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? http://maplesoft.com/products/mapleta/latex2ta/index.aspx

Comment: You might try converting via `html` or `xml`, but I doubt a ready solution exists.

Comment: how can I do that? also I don't know if it is important but I'm using a Macintosh

Comment: @phx I think that would convert a big document in Latex but if I only want an equation? Also I'm not sure how to use the link.

Comment: It seems that you have to upload your Maple document and will receive a LaTeX one. However, I have never used Maple. You might try it and see whether it works or not. Just put all your equations in one file and let the converter do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: No idea how much [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17769208) can parse, but it works for simple expressions, at least. In short, use [SnuggleTeX's MathML converter](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/snuggletex/MathInputDemo) to convert a TeX expression to MathML, then paste the MathML into Maple as described [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/expressions/pasteMathML).

Comment: @MikeRenfro Can you make an answer from your comment?

Comment: @Schweinebacke Will try to do that as soon as I get back to where I have a copy of Maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in comments, here's a short demonstration.

## [SnuggleTeX's Math Input Demo Site](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/snuggletex/MathInputDemo)

Entered `1+e^{i \pi}` into their math mode input field, and hit go. Got the following result:

[image]

I then copied their MathML to the clipboard

## Maple

Started up Maple 2015, and pasted the clipboard into a new Document. Was prompted for whether I wanted to treat the clipboard as 2D Math, so I clicked Yes.

[image]

Got the expression into the Maple Document:

[image]